# How to check for corrupt records in Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a hive table on which data gets incremented daily. On a particular day some corrupt records have been inserted into table. Is there a way I can match the table with master file on HDFS and pull the corrupt records from Hive

OR

How can I identify corrupt records in hive table with 1 million rows?

Comment: 1. When you say "data gets incremented daily", are you manually loading data from HDFS file to Hive

Comment: @BruceWayne - Yes, files are being added to HDFS daily after which the data is loaded to Hive table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either **`join, except1`** to find out the corrupt records loaded into Hive table vs file.

**`Example:`**

```
//read the file
val df=spark.read.<format>("<path>")

//read hive table
val df1=spark.read.table("<db>.<hive_table_name>")

//without using md5 hash
df.exceptAll(df1).show()
df1.exceptAll(df).show()

//create md5 hash by concatenating all column values
val df2=df.withColumn("md_hash",md5(concat_ws(",",df.columns.map(c => col(c)): _*))).select("md_hash")

val df3=df1.withColumn("md_hash",md5(concat_ws(",",df.columns.map(c => col(c)): _*))).select("md_hash")

//get non matching rows from df2 that are not existed in df3
df2.except(df3).show()
df2.exceptAll(df3).show()

//get non matching rows from df3 that are not existed in df2
df3.exceptA(df2).show()
df3.exceptAll(df2).show()

//or using full outer join
df3.join(df2,df3("md_hash") === df2("md_hash"),"full").
filter((df2("md_hash").isNull || df3("md_hash").isNull)).
show(10,false)
```

Comment: Thank you for the details. Can you please explain purpose of "md5 hash by concatenating all column values" here

Comment: @SNS, We are calculating **`md5`** hash for all columns then it's easy to find out `except`(difference) between two dataframes and we can do that using without md5 too **`df.except(df1).show()`** (or) **`df1.except(df).show()`** can give you expected result without md5 hash.

Comment: Thank You @Shu for the explanation